# Get values from an array. JMeter

Tags: arrays, jmeter

I have values in file: 
en-us, de-de, es-es, cs-cz, fr-fr, it-it, ja-jp, ko-kr, pl-pl, pt-br, ru-ru, tr-tr, zh-cn, zh-tw.

how can I get this values for one request?
I want to create a query that takes the value of these in turn and writes the variable

Answer (score 0):

This scenario can be achieved using Jmeter component "CSV Data Set Config"

Please refer to below mentioned link:

[Jmeter CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

Hope this will help

Comment: When I use CSV Data Set Config - in sampler result i have instead my variadle - <EOF>. And all request is failed

Comment: you are passing variable in which sampler?

Comment: screen my test plan
[link](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/22053/20140801-4ka6-75kb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, not enough karma. In response to above questions your path is probably wrong. If you use a debug sampler to show what path the CSV reader is taking I think you will find it is looking at something like C:/Jmeter/C:/path/to/CSV/file.

Another option for completing this is to use inline CSVRead. In your HTTP request use code like this -

${__CSVRead(etc/filters.csv,0)}${__CSVRead(etc/filters.csv,next)}

etc/filters is the RELATIVE path from Jmeters active running directory. In my case this evaluates to

C:/git/JmeterScripts/etc/filters.csv

In either case, I am sure your problem is that Jmeters active running directory is not what you think it is. I have had this problem several times with the same  error.